# How can i create deleted controller again with same name?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller

Is it possible to create same deleted controller again with same name in laravel?

I had one controller with name of `SellerController`, unfortunately i was delete it and now i try to create controller with same name but, it shows error like `Controller already exists!`

Comment: run `composer dump-autoload` and recreate it

Comment: @M.Elwan it shows same error

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` & `php artisan cache:clear` (or possibly the other way around) and then recreate it

Comment: Thanks @AndyHolmes but got same error.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually deleted? And then you run cache:clear and then dump-autoload?

Comment: Try creating the file manually and see if you are getting any errors

Comment: @AndyHolmes yes i check it i delete it.

Comment: your controllers folder isn't changed? and the file is physically deleted?

Comment: Your problem is not resolved? Did you run those three commands i mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @Learner you solve my problem but stackoverflow accept your answer after 6 min.

Comment: Oh ok, DIscussion was going on here so i thought your problem didnt get resolved.

Comment: Should be able to accept your answer now

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three most important commands if your Laravel is not working as expected after some modifications in .env or database folder or when you try to create some model or controller with same name as deleted one:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```